# Creating a table in BigQuery using the PHP api with schema

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a table in bigquery using the php api.

I can create a table without a schema just fine, but when I provide a schema I get errors. It looks like I'm using the wrong syntax, however I tried just about any formatting I could think of and couldn't find a single example of what I'm trying to achieve.

I use a string literal for the fields parameter for testing. My code looks like this:

```
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'keyFilePath' => [keyfilepath],
        'projectId' => [projectid],
        'location' => [location]
    ]);

    /** @var Dataset $dataSet */
    $dataSet = $bigQuery->dataset('my-data-set');

    $fieldString = '{"name": "myfield","type": "STRING","mode": "REQUIRED"}' . "\n" . '{"name": "anotherfield", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}';
    $options = [
        'fields' => $fieldString
    ];
    $dataSet->createTable('mytable', $options);
```

Which gives the error:

> "Invalid field selection {\"name\":\"myfield\""

Or alternatively, when I format the "$fieldString" like this:

```
$fieldString = '[{"name": "myfield","type": "STRING","mode": "REQUIRED"}, {"name": "anotherfield", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"}]';
```

I get the error:

> Invalid FieldMask '[{\"name\":\"myfield\",\"type\":\"STRING\",\"mode\":\"REQUIRED\"},{\"name\":\"anotherfield\",\"type\":\"STRING\",\"mode\":\"REQUIRED\"}]'. Map keys should be represented as [\"some_key\"].

I've also tried to create the table first and then update it like so:

```
$table = $dataSet->createTable('mytable');
$table->update($options);
```

But I get the same errors. Even when I use the the json representation exactly like [shown here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#tablefieldschema) the problem persists.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:

I actually first tried this, before I switched to a string literal for the fields:

```
    $fields = [
        ['name'=> 'myfield', 'type' => 'INTEGER', 'mode' => 'REQUIRED'],
        ['name'=> 'anotherfield', 'type' => 'INTEGER', 'mode' => 'REQUIRED']
    ];
    $options = [
        'schema' => $fields
    ];
    $dataSet->createTable('mytable', $options);
```

This yields the error:

> "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"schema\" at 'table': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list."

Then I edited the code to look like this:

```
    $fields = [
        ['name'=> 'myfield', 'type' => 'INTEGER', 'mode' => 'REQUIRED'],
        ['name'=> 'anotherfield', 'type' => 'INTEGER', 'mode' => 'REQUIRED']
    ];
    $options = [
        'fields' => $fields
    ];
    $dataSet->createTable('mytable', $options);
```

Which gives:

> Warning: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I didn't mention this in my question before because I thought it wasn't relevant. In hindsight it probably is, but my problem still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as `$fieldString` that is `$fields` array

like this:

```
 $fields = [
    [
        'name' => 'field1',
        'type' => 'string',
        'mode' => 'required'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'field2',
        'type' => 'integer'
    ],
];
```

then

```
$schema = ['fields' => $fields];
$table = $dataset->createTable($tableId, ['schema' => $schema]);
```

See example [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/src/create_table.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was actually the first thing I tried, but the errors I received seemed so obvious that I didn't mention it. I've updated my question with added examples, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: Check again the schema -> fields -> your array notation. You don't have a line to set the 'schema' key.

Comment: That's it. Thanks again. This whole problem illustrates nicely why exceptions should have useful messages. It started with me reading "Unknown name \"schema\" at 'table'" and thinking "this key obviously has the wrong name".